# DOM Elements disappear when put into a Telerik RadWindow

Tags: javascript, dom, tree, dialog, telerik

I have a custom javascript tree that I need to display inside a web page using Telerik Rad.  My tree is rooted at an element named `fptree`.   I can pop the tree up in a dialog as follows:

```
var rwm = parent.GetRadWindowManager();
var w = rwm.open(null, null, document.getElementById('fptree'), 400, 500);
```

This displays my tree in a modal dialog window as desired.  However, I can no longer locate any of the entries in the tree, including `$("#fptree")`.  The tree expands nodes by looking them up by id, but the callbacks fail because none of the nodes, or parent, can be found.   The nodes are displayed correctly in the dialog, so they must be available somewhere.

I have tried using `dump_dom` from [lemoda.net](http://www.lemoda.net/javascript/dump-dom/dump-dom.html) and the fptree elements do not show up in the dump.  (They do show up if I dump the DOM before opening the RadWindow dialog.)

Can anybody explain how I can access the DOM elements inside the RadWindow dialog?  (This all works inside a jquery-ui dialog, but I need to integrate with the Telerik based page to get a consistent style.)

Answer (score 0):

RadWindow moves the content in the DOM - the popup it generates (it does that via JS) is the first child of the `<form>` element. Perhaps that has something to do with some code not being able to find them.

One other thing I found is this: http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/129174-fix-a-radwindow-created-client-side-does-not-generate-its-contenttemplate-when-se
That states that dynamically generated content templates do not work as expected. so you should try declaring a RadWindow with its ContentTemplate in the markup and open that. Something like:

```
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:RadWindow>
        <div id="myTree">this is my tree</div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="open dialog and put nodes in it" OnClientClick="openWnd(); return false;" runat="server" />
        <script>
            function openWnd() {
                var wnd = $find("<%=RadWindow1.ClientID%>");
                wnd.show();
                var templateElem = wnd.get_contentElement();
                //this happens after show()
                templateElem.appendChild(document.getElementById("myTree"));
            }
        </script>
```